# ZPL Command RFID

Tags: rfid, zpl

I'm trying to encode a rfid tag using a zebra printer, sending these commands it encodes but I need to cut or hide some part of the number

```
^XA
^RS8
^RFW,H
^FDD020004D^FS
^XZ
```

The commands above records this to the tag D020004D000000000000 but I dont need the zeros. How can I remove them or hide them, I have tried to reduce the EPC memory size but results in a different code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The EPC field has a specific size.  When you read the tag you should be able to specify the offset and number of bytes to read. Need to handle this during the read not the write.